# How to achieve rounded corner with a diagonal inside it in a shape drawable?

Tags: android, android-drawable, shapes

how to achieve rounded corner and a diagonal shape as shown in figure in android shape xml? Thanks

[image: Rounded image with diagonal inside]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`rotate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable) element with [`layer-list`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                    android:dashGap="5dp"
                    android:dashWidth="8dp"
                    android:width="8dp"
                    android:color="#989898"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>
        <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="60"
                android:toDegrees="45"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%">

            <shape
                    android:shape="line">
                <stroke
                        android:dashGap="5dp"
                        android:dashWidth="8dp"
                        android:width="8dp"
                        android:color="#989898"/>
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```